# Not in scope: data constructor ‘Cons’

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble with the following Data Type and Function:

```
module Lib
    (intListProd) where

data IntList = Empty
             | Cons Int IntList
  deriving Show

intListProd :: IntList -> Int
intListProd Empty = 1
intListProd (Cons x xs) = x * intListProd xs
```

But if I try to use it within ghci, I get errors about 'Cons' and 'Empty' not being in the scope:

```
*Main Lib> intListProd (Cons 3 (Cons 2 (Cons 4 Empty)))

<interactive>:19:14: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Cons’

<interactive>:19:22: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Cons’

<interactive>:19:30: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Cons’

<interactive>:19:37: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Empty’
```

I'm using stack, so I use 'stack ghci' to enter the shell.

The code is not my own, I'm trying to follow the examples at the end of chapter 2 in the [School of Haskell Introduction to Haskell](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/introduction-to-haskell) tutorial by Brent Yorgey.

I've noticed the "Learn you a Haskell" also uses the 'Cons' constructor in the "Recursive Data Types" section. Is 'Cons' something that should be included in GHC that I don't have for some reason?? What about 'Empty'?

Comment: In the type signature of `intListProd`, you have `Int List`. I assume that is meant to be `IntList`?

Comment: Oh, yeah; that wasn't in my code, I typed this by hand. :)  Fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module Lib
    (intListProd) where
```

You're not exporting any constructor of `IntList`. Export them, so that they're available to other modules:

```
module Lib
    (intListProd, IntList(..)) where
           --     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting, though; I was able to use other data type definitions without exporting the constructor in this way. For example `data Person = Person String Int Thing deriving Show`. What makes the IntList constructor special?

Comment: See @ReidBarton's answer. GHC didn't load all definitions.

Answer (score 1):

The secret is here in the GHCi prompt:

```
*Main Lib>
```

For modules marked with a `*` (usually there is exactly one of these) *all* definitions are in scope, not just ones that are exported from the module. Modules without a `*` obey the usual rule: only exported names are visible in GHCi.